# How to in-text cite a series of paper with nothing in between in APA?

Tags: citations

E.g. Would it be OK if I write:

The papers by Bechara, Damasio, Damasio, and Anderson (1994), Bechara, Damasio, Tranel, and Damasio (1997) and Bechara, Damasio, Damasio, and Lee (1999)  shows that .....

?

Comment: Why not write "X affects Y (citation1; citation2; citation3)"? Why is it necessary to write these out front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there is a rule that covers this. the best I can find is on the [APA Style Blog](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/01/writing-in-text-citations-in-apa-style.html):

> When multiple studies support what you have to say, you can include multiple citations inside the same set of parentheses. Within parentheses, alphabetize the studies as they would appear in the reference list and separate them by semicolons. In running text, you can address studies in whatever order you wish. Here are two examples:

The running text example has each citation in a separate sentence so it is not a perfect match. I think the main point is that in the text, you can do what you want. That said, this is one I would either let the copy editor deal with or more likely try and write the sentence in a way that allows the citations to be parenthetical material.